# how can i remove buttons and text like row in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I could not create a row, so I did like this, but I need a row for google button and telephone number button.

my css codes:

```
.google-button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3%;
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.alternative-sign-in-buttons {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.telephone-number-btn {
  width: 41%;
  height: 50.3px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  left: 61%;
  bottom: 18%;
}

.deneme {
  font-size: 14px;
  
}
```

my html codes:

```
<div className="alternative-sign-in-buttons">
        <GoogleAuth />
        <button className="telephone-number-btn">
          <p className="deneme">Sign in with telephone number</p>
        </button>
        </div>
```

here codes image:
[image: 1]

Comment: Why did you give `position: absolute` to the button? It makes it harder to handle, and causes most of the problems here.

Comment: @SinanYaman im new in this concept, idk actually

Comment: Check my answer, and read more about `flexbox` I linked there. It will make it really easy to handle this type of situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that code in ".telephone-number-btn" css.
i mean:

```
.telephone-number-btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 41%;
  height: 50.3px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15px;
  left: 61%;
  bottom: 18%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to center the "Sign in with telephone number" text inside the button?

This should center it easier. And I also saw that your Google button to the left was higher in height so I also set the height to 40px, making the height the same.

```
    .telephone-number-btn {
      display: flex;
      width: 41%;
      height: 40px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By giving `position: absolute` you remove the element from the html flow. Here is a nice [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/In_Flow_and_Out_of_Flow) to read more about it.

I created a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-1d9go?file=/src/index.js) form using html and css in react, you can take it from there if you want.

Basically, making the buttons container a [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you handle the position of the buttons really easily